# Accessing Background Service Through MainActivity

Tags: android, service, background, location

So i have a background service which gets location updates and I want to access the service from my tabActivity. (The method is static)

Can you tell me how to achieve that ?
if i try xxxService.yyyMethod() it is not working.

I am talking about a background service started by the activity, then the activity was closed by the user and restarted. The service was bound to the same activity and also start() (so it continues to exist even after activity is closed). By not working I mean the method is not returning anything While it is supposed to. Also, any statements after the method call doesnt execute. – Ishwar 27 secs ago edit

In the activity:
Bounding:
*

```
mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {    
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
                temp="LocationService bound";

                locationService = ((LocationService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
                locationService.setProfile(Profile);
                locationService.start();
                Log.e("COnnected","");
                mBound = true;              
            }
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
                mBound = false;
            }
        };
```

*

The error area:
*

```
LocationService.setProfile(homeProfile); (works fine)       
LocationService.getL(); (Any statement beyond this point doesnt get executed)
Log.e("Executed","LS");                     settingsActivity.status.append(Boolean.toString(LocationService.isRunning()));
```

*

If I comment out the 2nd line, 3rd and 4th line gets executed, otherwise it doesnt!
P.S: If I dont quit my activity, everything works. The problem only occurs if I quit my activity and restart it.

Comment: "it is not working...?".. explain more.. what is happening?

Comment: I am talking about a background service started by the activity, then the activity was closed by the user and restarted. The service was bound to the same activity and also start() (so it continues to exist even after activity is closed).

By not working I mean the method is not returning anything While it is supposed to. Also, any statements after the method call doesnt execute.

Comment: Updated the question with more info

Answer (score 0):

You can only call Activities from a `TabActivity`. You need to set a specific activity for the tab and then access the method of the `Service` from that activity. So basically your `xxxService.yyyMethod()` call should be in the activity.

Comment: That is what i am doing! I am not getting a compile error or anything, but my app just doesnt return the value that the yyyMethod is supposed to! In fact, it just stops the execution..

Comment: I am talking about a background service started by the activity, then the activity was closed by the user, restarted. The service was bound and also start() (so it continues to exist even after activity is closed).

Comment: I'll give you relevant snippets: (I have around 10 classes!)
Activity:
LocationService.setProfile(Profile); (Works fine)
LocationService.getL(); (Execution stops at this statement, all statements after this statement gets ignored)

Service:
public static Location getL() {
  return L;
 } 
static Location L=null; (Class variable)

Comment: Updated the question with more info

Comment: is your service using variables from the activity? maybe that is why when the activity is killed, the variables are destroyed and the service fails.